# CiviCRM 5.37 > CiviCRM 5.43 upgrade, drush cvupdb, ALTER TABLE civicrm_note CHANGE COLUMN note_date Invalid use of NULL value

Tags: upgrade

Not much ( not at all ) regarding this found via https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues.

```
[code] => -1
[message] => DB Error: unknown error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => ALTER TABLE civicrm_note CHANGE COLUMN
`note_date` `note_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT
current_timestamp() COMMENT 'Date attached to the note'
[nativecode=1138 ** Invalid use of NULL value]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => ALTER TABLE civicrm_note CHANGE COLUMN `note_date`
`note_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT
'Date attached to the note' [nativecode=1138 ** Invalid use of NULL
value]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error"
code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler
prefix="" info="ALTER TABLE civicrm_note CHANGE COLUMN `note_date`
`note_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT
 Date attached to the note' [nativecode=1138 ** Invalid use of NULL
 value]"]
 )

PEAR_Exception: "DB Error: unknown error"
* ERROR TYPE: DB_Error
* ERROR CODE: -1
* ERROR MESSAGE: DB Error: unknown error
* ERROR MODE: 16
* ERROR USERINFO: ALTER TABLE civicrm_note CHANGE COLUMN `note_date` `note_date` 
timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT 'Date attached to the note' 
[nativecode=1138 ** Invalid use of NULL value]
* ERROR DEBUGINFO: ALTER TABLE civicrm_note CHANGE COLUMN `note_date` `note_date` 
timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT 'Date attached to the note' 
[nativecode=1138 ** Invalid use of NULL value]
#0 /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core- 
minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#1 /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(998): PEAR_Error- 
>__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "ALTER TABLE civicrm_note 
CHANGE COLUMN `note_date` `note_date` timestamp NOT ...")
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue caused by empty timestamps in 'civicrm_note' according to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971586/mysql-alter-table-causes-error-invalid-use-of-null-value/22971654)**
The fix: run MySQL query before upgrade or if/when upgrade stuck.
In my case, this page http://example.org/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1  throws the MySQl error but after running the query below and refreshing the http://example.org/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 it all went well.

```
UPDATE  `civicrm_note`
SET `note_date`  = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE `note_date`  IS NULL;
```